# Enforce newlines before object literals in ESLint

Tags: eslint

I am trying to enforce something similar to `"brace-style": ["error", "allman"]` but for object literals like this one:

```
// Incorrect:
const x = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
};

// Correct:
const x =
{
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
};
```

What is the ESLint rule responsible for this style?

Comment: Beware that this can pose a problem with `return { foo: "bar" }` if the opening brace is on a new line, then the actual return value would be `undefined` rather than that object.

Comment: I can't actually find a rule for assignment style (other than multi-declarations). I don't think such a thing exists, at least not in the core set of rules. [operator-linebreak](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/operator-linebreak) can work if you want *all* assignment to have a newline after the `=` but it's not just objects.  There might be an extension somewhere or you might need to write one yourself.

Comment: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/5203